# C++ - How to instantiate object with constructor private in another class

Tags: c++, object, instantiation

I have a `class Piece` which I've put the default constructor has `private`, because I want to use only a specific constructor when the object is created:

```
class Piece
{
private:
  Piece();
public:
  Piece (int var1, int var2);
  ~Piece();
}
```

And now I have a `class Game` with has a `vector of Pieces`:

```
class Game
{
private:
  std::vector<Piece> m_pieces;
public:
  Game();
  ~Game();
  CreatePieces(); //<-- only here, I will create the Piece objects, not in the constructor
}
```

Now I want to have a `class Foo`, that contains a `Piece`:

```
class Foo
{
private:
  Piece m_piece;//ERROR!!! cannot access private member declared in class 'Piece'
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
}
```

**My question:**

Now I need to use the default constructor for the `m_piece` on the `Foo class`.
But I wanted to avoid that and use as I was using on the `Game class`.

Is there anyway I can keep my `Piece class` **as it is**, and create a `Piece object`, like in the `Foo class`, but initialize it with the constructor `Piece (int var1, int var2);` on my `Foo()` constructor?

Comment: Why declare a default constructor at all?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can initialise `m_piece` in the `Foo` constructor to call a specific constructor, e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo() : m_piece(0,0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Potter.